# Color only one item in numbered list

Tags: color, enumerate

Say I want all of the text on the second line "(a) Cat" to be in red (including the numbering and parentheses "(a)"). Everything else remains black. How do I do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\begin{enumerate}
\item Cat
\item Dog
\end{enumerate}
\item Two
\begin{enumerate}
\item Rat
\item Fox
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\begin{enumerate}\begingroup \color{red}
\item Cat\endgroup
\item Dog
\end{enumerate}
\item Two
\begin{enumerate}
\item Rat
\item Fox
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]